# C++ istream::read causes undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, binary-data

I using the following code to copy `n` character from binary file to `char*` variable :

```
 std::ifstream is ("write.abc", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length];

    std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);
    std::cout << "length of buffer: "<<strlen(buffer) <<endl;
    std::cout << "Content of buffer: "<<buffer <<endl;
.......
```

The content of my file:

[image]

This is the result of compilation:
[image]

My question is the following: I'm waiting to have:

> length of buffer: 13
>
> Content of buffer: abcdefghjklmn

Can some one, please, help me to interpret the result?

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for \0 at the end of your "string" this is what strlen uses to determine where the end of the string is.

Comment: You need to allocate length + 1 char, and put `\0` in `buffer[length]` after your read.

Comment: You can also use [begin, end) approach where 'end = begin + length + 1' if you want to just iterate through the buffer

Comment: @Felics Can you give us a detailled explanation please.

Comment: @SADOK STL algorithms work on [begin, end) intervals. Depending on how you want to use the buffer, you can "store" as a [begin, end) pair instead of null terminated C string. I will add more detailed description in one answer (even if it doesn't really answer your question)

Comment: I will be thankful for detailed description in one answer.

Comment: @SADOK I added few examples. If you need more I can add them, but I think they are enough to present the general idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your buffer is not terminated - you need to allocate an extra char and set it to `'\0'`, otherwise it's just an unterminated C string, so `strlen` will most likely return an invalid value, and attempting to print the string will typically produce garbage.

```
char * buffer = new char [length + 1]; // <<< allocate space for `length`
                                       //     characters + terminator

std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
// read data as a block:
is.read (buffer,length);
buffer[length] = '\0'; // <<< terminate C-style string
```

Note that using proper C++-style `std::string`s instead of old school C-style `char *` strings avoids this and other common problems, and is generally simpler and a lot more robust. If you're reading binary data rather than text, then consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Agreed. You could print the var 'length' and compare it to the output of strlen(buffer). They probably won't match. strlen searches for the first NULL-byte \0. It just finds one after 30 bytes

Comment: Using `std::string` probably won't work here, either.

Comment: @JamesKanze: oh - did I miss something - why not ?

Comment: Thank you @Paul R for your help. But I just want to comment your suggestion to use std::string instead of char*. 
In my case, I'm reading a binary file. that's why It is better to use char* when dealing with binary data.

Comment: @SADOK: OK - your example looks like text, but for a binary file you should probably use `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: @Paul R: Yes I agree with you. But it's a long story.
Anyway, I found That I have to use a std::vector < std::vector unsigned char> > to achieve my goal because I have to divide my file into three blocks.
Moreover, this fonction will be consumed by many other fonction already developing and they accept char* as a paramater.
If you have any suggestion, I will be thankful.

Comment: @SADOK: well if you're stuck with legacy C-style APIs then it may be easier for now to stick with your original approach, but for future code try to get away from C-style programming idioms and move towards a more C++-like approach - you'll find that it will pay dividends in the long run.

Comment: @PaulR The fact that his `length` may not be 100% accurate.  (But I'd missed that he'd opened the file in binary, which increases the chances of it being correct.)  You have to presize the `string`, and if you presize it incorrectly, then you'll still have junk at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that this is not answering the question. It is a followup to a comment**

One solution is to "store" the buffer as a `[begin, end)` range instead of null terminated C string. This has a big advantage over null terminate string - it can be used with **STL algorithms** without calling `strlen(...)` to find `end` element.

Following some examples:

```
std::stringstream is("some text\n");

if (is)
{
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    auto length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char* begin = new char [length];
    char* end = begin + length;

    std::cout<<"Reading "<<length<<" characters...\n";
    // read data as a block:
    is.read (begin,length);

    //print the data:
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));

    //print the data backwards:
    std::copy(std::reverse_iterator<char*>(end), std::reverse_iterator<char*>(begin), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    //create string from data:
    std::string str(begin, end);
    std::cout<<str;

    //sum the characters
    auto sum = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0);
    std::cout<<sum<<std::endl;

    //make them uppercase
    std::transform(begin, end, begin, toupper);
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```